# Production and staging api sub domains not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, subdomain, unicorn

I've been developing an API in Rails which I want to be accesible via `api.domain.com`. Locally, I modified my `/etc/hosts` file so `domain.com` and `api.domain.com` both resolve to localhost. For the staging and production I created CNAME aliases for `api.domain.com` and `api.staging.domain.com` to point to their respective servers `domain.com` and `staging.domain.com`.

In my `routes.rb` all my api routes are nested within this

```
namespace :api, path: '/', defaults: { format: 'json' }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
```

Locally it works just fine when i make requests to `api.domain.com` but when I try to do the same for the production and staging servers my requests fail, saying it can't match the route, for example:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/v1/users/2/likes"):
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/chunked.rb:43:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:576:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:670:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
  unicorn (4.8.3) bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Is there any other rails app running in `domain.com`? If so, is your webserver configured to forward the requests to the appropiate app?

Comment: There is only 1 app on that domain. And I've only created the CNAME aliases for api.* to point to the respective servers and the configuration you see in my routes.rb file.

Comment: I'm not sure about your production environment, but for your staging environment, it will probably not work. According to the routing guide, the constraints can be any method that the request object accepts, and that returns a `String`, like `subdomain`.

And according to the docs for that method, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-subdomain , that method will return `api.staging`, instead of `api`, which you're expecting in your routes.

Comment: In the staging environment it's perfectly okay that it resolves to api.staging, but neither in production not staging is it working.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing and yes, the subdomain resolves to "api.staging"...which is not really what I want :/

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
# inline
constraints: { subdomain: /api(?:\.(staging))?/ }


# config/routes.rb

# API Routes
constraints subdomain: /api(?:\.(staging))?/ do
  ...
end
```

The above would match: `api.example.com`, `api.staging.example.com`

You could easily add others to this as well, eg.

```
# config/routes.rb

# API Routes
constraints subdomain: /api(?:\.(staging|other))?/ do
  ...
end
```

The above would match: `api.example.com`, `api.staging.example.com`, `api.other.example.com`

Comment: I know I'm 2 years late, and working on another project now, but I used this for staging and it works fine, but production still won't work. I think it's a DNS issue or something.

Comment: Are you serving your application over https in both staging and production and if so, are you using the same SSL certificates? I'm just wondering if maybe you need a wildcard SSL certificate.

Comment: Yeah I think that might be the issue as well, our site has https, but the api endpoints don't seem to have it. Staging doesn't have https and works ok.